# How can I get Url without "index.php" in static block?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

When I use: `{{store url="forum"}}` it results in:  `www.domain.com/index.php/forum`.  I want the url without index.php .i.e. `www.domain.com/forum`.  What do I need to change for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need to use:

```
{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}
```

i hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

sorry about the last answer...i misunderstood your question.

there are a number of ways to accomplish what you want.

1. you can change the base URL by going to SYSTEM > CONFIGURATION > WEB > SECURE 
   and SYSTEM > CONFIGURATION > WEB > UNSECURE respectfully (this might have repercussions and must be used carefully!!!)
2. you can continue to use the base URL the way it is and work around it.

if you can explain what your specific problem i think i'll be able to help you.
feel free to respond
good luck

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimization* and ensure "Use Web Server Rewrites" is set to "Yes".